# I can't make scroll part of a web site

Tags: html, css, codepen

I'm building a clone site of [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/) for learning programming.
But I can't realize a scroll part of "Latest Blocks" area in [this page](https://etherscan.io/).

I have read source codes of the web site.
But all overflow properties regarding the part are set "hidden", not "scroll".
I can't understand this part.

My html and css codes are as follows.
Sorry for too long code and too many id attributes.
Please ignore there are same id attributes.
I'm newbie in programming.

I add CodePen link below for making you understand my code easily.
Could you show me how to do that.
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/pierogi/pen/zYvBrwb)

HTML

```
<div id="blocks">
  <div id="blocks-container">
    <div id="blocks-title-container">
      <h2 class="fontfamily-1 font-color-5 font-size-1 font-weight-600">Latest Blocks</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="scroll">
      <div id="scroll-part">
        <div id="scroll-part-container">
          <div id="scroll-row-1">
            <div id="scroll-row-1-1">
              <div id="scroll-row-1-1-left">
                <div id="scroll-row-1-1-left-icon">
                  <span id="scroll-row-icon-block" class="font-size-1 font-weight-500">
                    <span id="scroll-row-icon-text" class="font-size-1 font-weight-500 fontfamily-1">Bk</span>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div id="scroll-row-1-1-left-content">
                  <a id="scroll-row-1-1-left-content-number" class="fontfamily-1 font-size-1"
                    　href="/block/9873479">9873479</a>
                  <span id="countdown" class="font-color-4 fontfamily-1 font-weight-400 under-line-none">1 min 35 secs
                    ago</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="scroll-row-1-1-right" class="fontfamily-1 font-size-1 font-weight-400">
              <div id="scroll-row-1-1-right-sub">
                <div id="scroll-row-1-1-right-center">
                  <span id="scroll-row-1-1-right-miner" class="fontfamily-1 font-size-1 font-weight-400">
                    Miner
                    <a id="scroll-row-1-1-right-name" class="fontfamily-1 font-size-1 font-weight-400 font-color-6"
                      href="/address">Spark Pool</a>
                  </span>
                  <a id="scroll-row-1-1-right-txns" class="fontfamily-1 font-size-1 font-weight-400 font-color-6"
                    title="Transactions in this Block" href="/txns">115
                    txns</a>
                  <span id="scroll-row-1-1-right-blockTime" class="fontfamily-1 font-weight-400">in 2 secs</span>
                </div>
                <div id="scroll-row-1-1-right-reward">
                  <span id="scroll-row-1-1-right-reward-content" class="fontfamily-1 font-weight-500 font-size-4"
                    title="Block Reward">
                    2
                    <b>.</b>
                    0439Eth
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="hr-space">

          <!-- repeating <div id="scroll-row-1"> 8 times -->

          <hr class="hr-space">
          <div id="scroll-row-1">
            <div id="scroll-row-1-1">
              <div id="scroll-row-1-1-left">
                <div id="scroll-row-1-1-left-icon">
                  <span id="scroll-row-icon-block" class="font-size-1 font-weight-500">
                    <span id="scroll-row-icon-text" class="font-size-1 font-weight-500 fontfamily-1">Bk</span>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div id="scroll-row-1-1-left-content">
                  <a id="scroll-row-1-1-left-content-number" class="fontfamily-1 font-size-1"
                    　href="/block/9873479">9873479</a>
                  <span id="countdown" class="font-color-4 fontfamily-1 font-weight-400 under-line-none">1 min 35 secs
                    ago</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="scroll-row-1-1-right" class="fontfamily-1 font-size-1 font-weight-400">
              <div id="scroll-row-1-1-right-sub">
                <div id="scroll-row-1-1-right-center">
                  <span id="scroll-row-1-1-right-miner" class="fontfamily-1 font-size-1 font-weight-400">
                    Miner
                    <a id="scroll-row-1-1-right-name" class="fontfamily-1 font-size-1 font-weight-400 font-color-6"
                      href="/address">Spark Pool</a>
                  </span>
                  <a id="scroll-row-1-1-right-txns" class="fontfamily-1 font-size-1 font-weight-400 font-color-6"
                    title="Transactions in this Block" href="/txns">115
                    txns</a>
                  <span id="scroll-row-1-1-right-blockTime" class="fontfamily-1 font-weight-400">in 2 secs</span>
                </div>
                <div id="scroll-row-1-1-right-reward">
                  <span id="scroll-row-1-1-right-reward-content" class="fontfamily-1 font-weight-500 font-size-4"
                    title="Block Reward">
                    2
                    <b>.</b>
                    0439Eth
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#blocks {
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}

#blocks-container {
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1.2rem rgba(189, 197, 209, .2);
    height: 100% !important;
    position: relative;
    display: flex!important;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid #e7eaf3;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: space-between !important;

}

#blocks-title-container {
    border-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px) calc(.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
    align-items: center!important;
    justify-content: space-between!important;
    display: flex!important;
    padding: .75rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e7eaf3;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

#scroll {
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding: .75rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#scroll-part {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    direction: ltr;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}

#scroll-part-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: scroll;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
    unicode-bidi: isolate;
}

#scroll-row-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -7.5px;
    margin-left: -7.5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
}

#scroll-row-1-1 {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    direction: ltr;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-left {
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
    margin-right: 1.25rem!important;
    align-items: center!important;
    display: flex!important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-left-icon {
    margin-right: .5rem!important;
    display: flex!important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
}

#scroll-row-icon-block {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 0;
    width: 2.53906rem;
    height: 2.53906rem;
    padding: 0;
    color: #77838f;
    background-color: rgba(119, 131, 143, .1);
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
}

#scroll-row-icon-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #1e2022!important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: default;
    line-height: 0;
    text-align: center;
    user-select: none;
    direction: ltr;

}

#scroll-row-1-1-left-content {
    flex: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    direction: ltr;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: left;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-left-content-number {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3498db;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    direction: ltr;
}

#countdown {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: 0!important;
    display: block!important;
    font-size: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-right {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    direction: ltr;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #1e2022;
    text-align: left;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-right-sub {
    justify-content: space-between!important;
    display: flex!important;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

#scroll-row-1-1-right-content {
    flex: 0 0 66.66667%;
    max-width: 66.66667%;
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    direction: ltr;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-right-container {
    justify-content: space-between!important;
    display: flex!important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-right-center {
    white-space: nowrap!important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    direction: ltr;

}

#scroll-row-1-1-right-miner {
    margin-bottom: 0!important;
    display: block!important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-right-name {
    max-width: 132px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    direction: ltr;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-right-txns {
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap!important;
    direction: ltr;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-right-blockTime {
    color: #77838f!important;
    font-size: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap!important;
    direction: ltr;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-right-reward {
    display: block!important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
}

#scroll-row-1-1-right-reward-content {
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: .8px;
    border-top-right-radius: .25rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .25rem;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    color: #77838f;
    background-color: rgba(119, 131, 143, .1);
    line-height: 1.7;
    padding: .2rem .5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 3;
    text-align: center !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;

}

#scroll-row-1-1-right-reward-content::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: "";
    border-top: .7rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom: .7rem solid transparent;
    border-left: .7rem solid #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hr-space {
    margin-top: .75rem;
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
    opacity: .75;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7eaf3;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    display: block;
    unicode-bidi: isolate;
    margin-block-start: 0.5em;
    margin-block-end: 0.5em;
    margin-inline-start: auto;
    margin-inline-end: auto;
    direction: ltr;
}

#transactions {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
}

.font-color-1 {
    color: #6e777f;
}

.font-color-2 {
    color: #f9fcff;
}

.font-color-3 {
    color: #000000;
}

.font-color-4 {
    color: #77838f;
}

.font-color-5 {
    color: #4a4f55;
}

.font-color-6 {
    color: #3498db;
}

a:hover {
    color: #3799db;
}

.font-size-1 {
    font-size: .8125rem;
}

.font-size-2 {
    font-size: 1.01563rem;
}

.font-size-3 {
    font-size: .71094rem;
}

.font-size-4 {
    font-size: .60938rem;
}

.fontfamily-1 {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.font-weight-300 {
    font-weight: 300;
}

.font-weight-400 {
    font-weight: 400;
}

.font-weight-500 {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.font-weight-600 {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.under-line-none {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.hover-no-change-summary:hover {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding overflow:scroll ?

Comment: I have added overflow:scroll in #scroll-part-container of css.
And I have tried adding overflow:scroll in other div(#scroll, #scroll-part).
But they didn't work.

Comment: well scroll only works when the elements within container overflows the size of the container. try adding few more elements and see.

Comment: Sorry for above html code is difficult to read.
But I have already added elements within the container.
The comment "<!-Repeating <div id =" scroll-row-1 "> 8 times->" in the middle of above html code means that.

Comment: Remove `overflow: hidden;` from `div#scroll-part` and `div#scroll-part-container` and set `overflow: auto;` or `scroll` instead of `hidden` for `div#scroll`.

Comment: Also would be safer and more scalable to use classes, not id's, for styling

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you for your reply. And I'll use classes.